# Posting listed variable attribute in FreeMarker

Tags: java, web-applications, freemarker

[image: Problem Area on Home Page]

I am building a webapp using java and spark to list players on a home page. When a user clicks the button associated with the player that they want to start a game with, it should submit that specific player. However, right now when a player clicks on any button associated with a player name, it only posts the name of the last player in the list. I assume this is happening because once the page is finished rendering, `player` has been set to the final player in the list, so when `player.getName()` is posted, this is really only referencing the name of the final player in the list.

Does anyone know how I might be able to fix this? Other methods of submitting attributes of listed objects?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but `${player.getName()}` can be written as `${player.name}`.

Comment: Also please don't insert code as image... it can't be copy-pasted, indexed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have multiple forms with the same ID in the same HTML document. You should write something like these: `<form id='startgame${player?counter}'>`, and `startgame${player?counter}.submit()`.